# Is there a file that can be deleted to force SSMS to manually rebuild Intellisense?

Tags: ssms

I have a case where intellisense has stopped working completely.

- I have tried `Ctrl`-`Shift`-`R` and waited a few minutes. This has no effect.
- I changed the `Maximum script size` in '`Tools` | `Options` > `Text-Editor` > `Transact-SQL` > `Intellisense` to 5 MB. This briefly revived intellisense. But, it stopped working the next day. I tried increasing the size to `Unlimited`, but this had no effect.
- Intellisense is enabled.
- The issue occurs across all scripts.
- I have tried closing SSMS and restarting with no change.
- SSMS version 19.0.20209
- SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)                       16.200.48036

I am wondering if this is simply a corrupt file that can be  deleted and re-built from scratch when SSMS is started. If this is the case, what is the name and location of the file?

Comment: If you close and re-open SSMS, intellisense is still no-go?

Comment: Which version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)      16.200.48036 
I have tried closing and re-opening - the issue persists across all scripts.

Comment: Clutching at straws but on the "View" menu anything relevant shown if you select "ErrorList" or "output"

Comment: 0 Errors, 0 Warnings, 0 Messages on all documents and combinations of Build and IntelliSense.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing SSMS? Also, I'm not familiar with SMO, what does that have to do with SSMS?